# Gold price per kilo on Yahoo Finance API

Tags: price, gold, yahoo-finance

I monitor on Yahoo Finance the [gold price per ounce](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GC%3DF/chart?p=GC%3DF). But I learned that in US you buy gold per ounce, but in Europe we use per kilo.

How do I see the price per kilo on Yahoo Finance?

*I use a software for portfolio tracking which uses in background the Yahoo Finance API.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in your question is not spot gold, but (first) Comex futures.

For USD spot price of 1 Troy oz you can try https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAU:CUR or https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAUUSD:CUR (Bloomberg) or https://www.reuters.com/quote/XAU=X (Reuters) or https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XAUUSD=X/ (Yahoo Finance)

EUR spot price of 1 Troy oz https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAUEUR:CUR, GBP spot price of 1 Troy oz https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAUGBP:CUR, INR spot price of 1 Troy oz https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/XAUINR:CUR , etc.

Comex futures (USD / 1 Troy oz) https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/GC1:COM or https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GC=F/

Mini Gold futures https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/YG=F/

E-Mini Gold futures https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QO=F/

Tokyo futures (Japanese yen per gram, rather than oz)  https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/JG1:COM

Your software needs to be capable of translating a troy oz quote into a kilogram quote.

Answer (score 1):

1 kg is 32.1507 US Troy ounces. So you could just multiply each number by 32.1507.  Or find another API that tracks the gold price in a European market (it *should* be equivalent to prevent arbitrage, though).

Comment: Gold is measured in Troy Ounce, not the usual Avoirdupois Ounce.

Comment: @base64 Doh - thanks, I was thinking there was a different Ounce in Euro but forgot about Troy ounces. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The spot price for gold is quoted in US dollars per ounce, whatever country you're in.

Any other figures you see elsewhere require currency conversions and/or conversion to different mass systems.  Converting troy ounces to kilos can be done using 1oz = 31.1035g.  In other words, to get the price per kilo, multiply the price per ounce by 32.150722.

Currency conversions will never be exact.  But Kitco have a handy chart that includes the conversion [on their web site](https://www.kitco.com/gold_currency/index.html?currency=euro&timePeriod=6m&flag=gold&otherChart=no).